# i install sqlplus in ubuntu 16.04 but at last

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

but at last when I typed this than it ask me username and password but  I don't have any thing.

```
$ sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Feb 27 01:56:15 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Enter user-name:
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlplus seems to use sys user as default
this topic may help you! https://community.oracle.com/message/10205682#10205682

What you want is to create a new user.
default user is sys so you will need to connect to the db from the server itself (through ssh).
`sqlplus "/ AS SYSDBA` shall connect you as sys.

Comment: harshit@harshit-Lenovo-G450:~$ sqlplus "/ AS SYSDBA
> 
>
then what should i do after this?